# Quarkus ConfigMapping: how to map properties with keys with and without next level at the same time, like "fields" and "fields.excludes"

Tags: quarkus

Converting my app to use Quarkus `@ConfigMapping` is not easy, especially when the properties names may be used by other apps and you are not free to change them.

I have two keys like `fields`(set of string) and `fields.excludes`(another set of string). I want to know what I can do to map both of them. I tried:

```java
Set<String> fields();

@WithName("fields")
FieldsExcludes fieldsToExclude();

interface FieldsExcludes {
    Set<String> excludes();
}
...
```

No compilation error, but runtime error:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property app.operator.0000001.endpoint.0.fields.exclude is required but it could not be found in any config source
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getIndexedValues(SmallRyeConfig.java:114)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getValues(SmallRyeConfig.java:106)
    ...
```

Of course, I think Quarkus cannot tell if "fields" is a field of set, or a field of type `FieldsExcludes`. But this kind of configs are valid in YAML.

```yaml
    fields: [a,b,c,d]
    fields.exclude: [e]
```

(if I break line at 2nd line after `fields` it's not valid; but if I put it like this it's valid, at least for Intellij IDEA)

---

See here: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-yaml#configuration-key-conflicts, in the doc it's stated that it's valid; I can use a `~` as a null key. So `fields` as a list and `fields.exclude` as another object should be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK at last it seems already supported; the error is due to it's not defined as "Optional<>" so Quarkus can find it in one place but cannot in another. (YAML contains 2 `ConfigDetail`, one of them does not have `excludes`, **and it has no default value**)

The final code is like this:

```java
    interface ConfigDetail {
        Set<String> fields();

        @WithName("fields")
        Optional<FieldsToExclude> fieldsToExclude();
    }
...
    interface FieldsToExclude {
        Set<String> exclude();
    }
```

```yaml
          fields:
            ~: [a,b,c,d]
            exclude: [e]
          ...
          fields:
            ~: [a,b,c,d,e]
          ...
```